# Value of type ARRAY<STRUCT<value ARRAY<STRING>>> cannot be assigned to M.preferences_testing, which has type STRING

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, spring-cloud-gcp-bigquery

getting the below error
Value of type ARRAY<STRUCT<value ARRAY>> cannot be assigned to M.preferences_testing, which has type STRING

```
MERGE table1 M USING (
 
select  _id,ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT value from unnest(preferences) as p where p.name="sendOnly")  as prefer from table2    
  
) S ON M._ID = S._ID WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE 
SET 
  M._ID = S._ID, 
  M.preferences_testing=s.prefer  // here getting error
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
    _ID,    
    preferences_testing
  ) 
VALUES 
  (
 _ID,   
 prefer
  )
```

table 2 structure

```
fullname    mode            type    description
_id         NULLABLE    STRING  
preferences REPEATED    RECORD  
preferences.value   REPEATED    STRING  
preferences.name    NULLABLE    STRING
```

Table 1 structure

```
fullname    mode    type    description
preferences_testing NULLABLE    STRING  
_Id NULLABLE    STRING
```

I tried to convert ARRAY<STRUCT<value ARRAY>> to String but nothing worked